# How can I reset an add/remove field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input field in a twitter bootstrap form on a sidebar (that also uses jquery) that will add and remove a field by clicking a plus button or a minus button. Here is the html:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Fields</label>
        <div  class="control-group SearchRow" data-index="1">
            <div class="controls">
                <a title="Add name below" id="addRow1" href="#" tabindex="-1"> <i class="icon-plus"></i>
                </a> <input id="name1" type="text" class="span2 typeahead" />
                <a title="Remove name" href="#" id="removeRow1" tabindex="-1"> <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

When an input field is added, it adds the field dynamically in the html (the data-index increases by one, and the addRow1 is addRow2, removeRow1 is removeRow2, etc)

I have created a button that resets these fields, so that when fields are added or deleted, I can empty out whatever was written in the box. So far, the fields that are added can be reset with the following jquery:

```
 $sideBar.find('#ResetButton').on('click', function(){
        $sideBar.find('#form').trigger('reset');                        
    });
```

However, if I add some fields, enter input and delete some but not all fields, the remaining ones WON'T empty.

Here is a visual:

**Original form:**

+[ field  ]-

**Then I add some by clicking the plus button**

+[ blfgadfgadfgdaah   ]-

+[ field  ]-

+[ bldafbhdsfbhdsfhah   ]-

**push reset: and it works!**

+[ field  ]-

+[ field  ]-

+[ field  ]-

**BUT: if I go from original, add, and delete some, it will NOT clear.
Original:**

+[ field  ]-

**Then I add some fields using plus button**

+[ blahhhhhhhhhhhh   ]-

+[ field             ]-

+[ afdfbhdfbbdf      ]-

**delete some fields using minus button:**

+[ blahhhhhhhhhhhh  ]-

+[ field            ]-

**push reset:**

+[ blahhhhhhhhhhhh  ]-

+[ field  ]-

I have tried adding an id to the controls and resetting that but it doesn't work. Any suggestions???

Comment: Um...what? Having a hard time understanding what exactly you are looking for. Can you please provide a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: It would be very helpufl if yo ucode post at least a sample of your code, without it we have to guess what you wrote and what error you are making...

Comment: @PhilippeTrépanier, i have added more detail and code to my question...I know the answer can be solved by adding some form of reset to my jquery, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the code you are using to reset your form, try using:

```
var defaultVal = "";//Set your default value here
jQuery('#ResetButton').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('#form input.typeahead').val(defaultVal);                        
});
```

Hope this helps!